# Set-builder Notation - define score on set whose elements are associated with another set

Tags: notation

this is probably straight forward, but I'm not sure how to deal with it. I'm looking for a mathematical representation.

In principle, I dealing with a set, let's call it F that contains elements (which are strings) that are used to calculate the set of values (lets say its length) in C. Now I want to define a function on F that in principle uses the elements of C.

Something like this:

$\text{score}(F) = C_k \cdot \max\ C_k\ \forall k \in C\ \text{where } C_k = \text{length of} F_k$

What is the best way to describe this mathematically?
Thanks

Comment: How do F and C interact? - F could be anything and the value of the `score` function wouldn't change.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Well, the values of C are calculated using the values of F. Basically, F contains strings and the length of these strings is the value of C, e.g., $C_k = \text{lengh of } F_k$ And the score should be the median times the maximum of these scores in C.